# replace specific patterned indexed items in python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I wanted to replace the every 2 alternative items in the list. Example below:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 9, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 5, 2, 3]
```

Result should be:

```
[1, ' ' , ' ', 9,  ' ',  ' ', 2,  ' ', ' ', 3, ' ', ' ', 5, ' ', 3]
```

Last and first item should not be replaced

I have for loop brute force enumerate way to do this. I am curious if there is any easy and alternative way to do this.

Comment: What about that 3 at the end. Seems out of place

Comment: Last and first item should not be replaced. I posted an edit to the question (sorry)

Comment: `[x if i%3==0 else ' ' for i,x in  enumerate(a[:-1])]+[a[-1]]`

Comment: What's wrong with your for-loop?

Comment: Nothing wrong, i am looking for much do-it in place way or space efficient way

Comment: `a[1:-1] = [a[i] if i%3 ==0 else ' ' for i in range(1, len(a)-1)]`

Comment: @be_good_do_good for-loop would be in-place and the most space efficient, i.e. blhsing's answer.

Comment: Let me time it and check it out, will post my findings

Comment: sticking back to my for loop now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `for` loop of in-place changes would actually be the most efficient in both speed and space:

```
for i in range(1, len(a) - 1):
    if i % 3:
        a[i] = ' '
```

Comment: I like that. The valuable insight that you can use a simple loop *without* `enumerate` got lost in the more fanciful answers.

Comment: yup, the pythonista-reflex to not iterate over a list by iterating over the indices fooled the rest of us; but not you! nice!

Answer (score 3):

this is a variant with a list-comprehension (creates a new list):

```
lst = [a[0]] + \
      [item if n % 3 == 2 else ' ' for n, item in enumerate(a[1:-1])] + \
      [a[-1]]
```

or a bit more concise if you want to do it in-place:

```
a[1:-1] = [item if n % 3 == 2 else ' ' for n, item in enumerate(a[1:-1])]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use slice assignment to mutate only the indexes that need changing:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 9, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 5, 2, 3]
a[1:-1:3] = ' ' * len(a[1:-1:3])
a[2:-1:3] = ' ' * len(a[2:-1:3])
# [1, ' ', ' ', 9, ' ', ' ', 2, ' ', ' ', 3, ' ', ' ', 5, ' ', 3]
```

Or with better space efficiency, not creating the unnecessary slices and strings:

```
a[1:-1:3] = (' ' for _ in range(1, len(a)-1, 3))
a[2:-1:3] = (' ' for _ in range(2, len(a)-1, 3))
```

Comment: damn that's nice! did not think of it... +1!

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I don't quite like that it is creating the two slices just for the length. One could do some better math there :)

Comment: Yeah, just use `len(range(1, len(a)-1,3)` instead

Comment: I am actually confused which one to accept as an answer :) yours or @hiroprotagonist

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Had the same idea now. Went for the generator as it does not build the auxiliary string.

Comment: how about `from itertools import repeat; a[1:-1:3] = a[2:-1:3] = repeat(' ')`?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist That would be nice, wouldn't it. But the assigned iterable must produce exactly as many elements as the length of the slice to be assigned. One does feel there should the intelligence to just grab as many as you need from an infinite generator ;)

Comment: @schwobaseggl oh, yes, you are right. that will not work in general... (and again: "schwobaseggl"?! really?! q8) )

Comment: @hiroprotagonist You seem to know the meaning ;) I had to google "q8" in the urban dictionary though... thx for the graphic imagery in my head now

Comment: ooops... what does q8 mean? hope nothing that offends? this "q8)" is just my stupid usual smiley (sunglasses and a baseball-cap; not that i'd ever wear one...). and yes: speaking an abomination of german myself... (oh, found "q8"... should probably refrain from using it in the future...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180247/discussion-between-schwobaseggl-and-hiro-protagonist).